# Magento 2 function insertOnDuplicate()

Tags: magento2.3, database, import

How can we implement **insert on duplicate update** using non-primary key or non-key field using Magento's function **insertOnDuplicate**?
Or is there any other way then please suggest.

Answer (score 6):

the function `insertOnDuplicate` transforms the array you pass as parameter into this sql query:

```
INSERT INTO
    table_name
VALUES
    (....)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    (field1 = value1, field2 = value2)
```

This does not depend on the a certain field. The update part is executed `ON DUPLICATE KEY` which means when any unique constraint receives a duplicate value. If you don't have unique constraints, this will never get executed.